# LuaLaTeX - Table (tabularx) Can't get rid of underfull hbox (badness 10000)

Tags: tables, luatex, tabularx, multicolumn, underfull

Ok so I have tried various solutions to this problem and the ~10 underfull hbox warning have been reduced to 1. But this one's really sticky and I'm at my wit's end.

The warning is directed to the ending of the *tabularx* environment (not the table environment) and I highly suspect that it has something to do with the last column, especially the multicolumn I used to work around the math mode (that I created, called O) because I don't wan't the header to be in Math font.
I also find it weird that not the entire space of that column is used.
And also, the cmidrule-line that goes from column 2-5 *didn't go all the way through* like toprule and bottomrule so I had to shorten it negatively on the right side
"cmidrule(lr{-13.5pt})...".
I don't know what I did to cause this but I know that this was not always the case...

That's all the information I can give you, I hope there is a simple solution to this, I've been sitting at this for hours now :(((

EDIT: The warning specifies to the alignment, the full information is here:
"Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 345--345"
(this is the end of the tabularx environment)

Please don't kill me for my (probably) Spaghetti code, here is a shortened version of the table,:

```
%(these are all the packages I put in so far, don't know if it matters much)
\documentclass[paper=a4, titlepage, fontsize=14pt, DIV=calc, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[autostyle = true, german = quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary} %tried to use this but tabularx is probably the better option for my use
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amsfonts}\usepackage{amssymb}

%----------------------now to the table----------------------%

% math mode for the percentages
\newcolumntype{O}{>{$\displaystyle\hsize=0.8\hsize\RaggedRight}X<{$}}


\begingroup

\begin{table}[t]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

%just to make the horizontal lines touch the vertical one, irrelevant for this issue
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.05\hsize\RaggedRight}X| >{\hsize=1.15\hsize\RaggedRight}X
>{\hsize=0.9\hsize\RaggedRight}X
>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\RaggedRight}X
O
@{}}

\toprule
Name &
Bedeutung &
Beispiel &
Entscheidungskriterium &
\multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize\RaggedRight}X}{Wahrscheinlichkeit} \\

\cmidrule(r{7.75pt}){1-1} \cmidrule(lr{-13.5pt}){2-5}

Höchste Karte & Keine der unteren Kombinationen & A♠ {\color{red}K♦} J♠ 7♣ 4♣ & Höhe  der einzelnen Karten & 17,41 \% \\
Straight Flush & Straße in einer Farbe & 8♣ 9♣ 10♣ J♣ Q♣ & Höchste Karte & 0,028 \% \\
Royal Flush & Straße in einer Farbe mit Ass als höchste Karte & {\color{red}10♦ J♦ Q♦ K♦ A♦} & Split Pot & 0,003 \%  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\endgroup
```

This is what it currently looks like. Don't worry about the contents, I cut most of it out in my code to make it easier to understand but for the image, I think it doesn't matter if the entire content is still there:

[image: table image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I can't really help with the main question, but the hyphenation "th-ree" is simply dreadful.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even notice that. I will fix that. Thank You :)

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`  please post an example of the warning that you are asking about that does not generate errors

Comment: Oh I didn't know this would be necessary but it makes sense. It's my first post here and I'm a latex beginner so I wasn't sure about the stackexchange etiquette and maybe the smart people here can find my mistake without needing a fully working document. And @DavidCarlisle actually did, I'm the happiest person ever :)).

Comment: oh thats you haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the underfull box to remove the warning

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} >{\hsize=1.05\hsize\RaggedRight}X| >{\hsize=1.15\hsize\RaggedRight}X
>{\hsize=0.9\hsize\RaggedRight}X
>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\RaggedRight}X
O
@{}}
```

You also need

```
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize$\displaystyle\RaggedRight}X<{$}}
```

so the hsize change is in scope at the end of the cell.

You also need to something about long german words:-)

[image]

Comment: You are my lord, you are my savior. I will forever be in your debt.